Can't get Basic Authentication to work in nginx
On a Debian 12 machine I installed nginx (nginx/1.22.1).
Because I still have Apache running, I changed the 2 listen directives in sites-available/default from 80 to 8000. Nothing else was changed.
Next, I created a second file in sites-available (and enabled it through a symlink) with the following content:
server {

  listen 8000;
  listen [::]:8000;

  root /webdav;

  location / {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file "/etc/nginx/.pwd";
  }
}

The /etc/nginx/.pwd file exists, has the correct user:password content, and is readable for nginx.
Syntax check passes, and nginx starts.
However, when I go to the URL http://192.168.0.150:8000/webdav in the browser, nginx shows the index.html file in the webdav directory without asking for credentials.
I have tried clearing the web browser cache, moved the auth_basic_user_file directive from the location block to the server block (as another post suggests).
Nothing helps.
What am I doing wrong ?
Is there a way to debug what is happening (or rather, what should happen, but does not) ?

You shouldn't put "webdav" in the URL.  That's a filesystem name that doesn't get exposed.  That shouldn't affect this problem, but the URL you want is "/".

Thanks Tim, but I don't quite understand.
I want to hide the location /webdav behind authentication, not /.
If I leave out webdav, the index.html of / is exposed.

And to be more clear: /webdav is nothing more than a directory in /var/www/html.

Well, then, you want root /var/www/html, right?  The root directive specifies the FILESYSTEM location of your document tree.  It has nothing to do with URLs.

Yep, that was it.
And after all it must also have been browser cache problems.
Did not obey the rule in IT to not change several things at once...
